# AngularJS $resource append full webdir path to request

Tags: html, angularjs, routes

I have the following

```
var API = $resource('/api/:object/:action', {
            action: '@action',
            object: '@object'
        },            
        save:  { method: 'POST'},
        delete:{ method: 'DELETE'},
        update:{ method: 'PUT'}
});

a = new API({object: 'test',id: 2, name: 'name2'});    
a.$save(function(u){ console.log(u); });
```

the request have the following url  `http://mylocalhost/home/rkmax/myproject/api/test/` and the correct `http://mylocalhost/api/test/`, the weirdest thing is that when I run my app showing the file into the route, like `http://mylocalhost/myapp.php` works fine.

my project is in the `/home/rkmax/myproject` path but i dont understand why $resource append that to the path

can help me with this weird error, my app uses html5Mode for all UI

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

the url of the app is `http://mylocalhost/app` and the API is `http://mylocalhost/api`